# Create nested comments array from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, recursion

I would like to use the [Hacker News Algolia API](https://hn.algolia.com/api) ([exact query](https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=comment,story_24120336)) to find comments, and then create a nested JSON structure from the data. I know I need to use recursion, but I am not too sure how.

This is the structure I would like:

```
comment1
  comment2
    comment3
comment4
comment5
```

In JSON:

```
[
  {
    "text": "eee",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "123",
        "childeren": [
          {
            "text": "rew"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "comment4",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "text": "comment5",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

The issue is that the API doesn't return comments in the format above. Returned comments have attribute `parent_id` which is a reference to their parent comment's `objectID`. So if you have the following nested `objectID`s:

```
foo
  bar
    foobar
```

`foobar`'s `parent_id` is `bar` and `bar`'s `parent_id` is `foo`. And finally `foo`'s `parent_id` is the Hacker News post ID, in this case `24120336`.

What I have so far [[repl]](https://repl.it/repls/DiscreteLostAbstracttype):

```
import axios from 'axios'

interface Comment {
  created_at: string;
  author: string;
  comment_text: string;
  story_id: number;
  story_title: string;
  story_url: string;
  parent_id: number | null;
  objectID: string;
}

function getChildren(comment: Comment, allComments: Comment[]) {
  const children = allComments.filter(
    (c) => String(c.parent_id) === comment.objectID
  );
  const fullChildren = children.forEach((child) =>
    getChildren(child, allComments)
  );
  return fullChildren;
}

const main = async () => {
    const { data } =
    await axios.get<{ hits: Comment[] }>(
      "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=comment,story_24120336"
  );

  data.hits.forEach((comment) => {
    // Check if comment is top level
    if (String(comment.parent_id) === "24120336") {
      console.log(getChildren(comment, data.hits));
    }
  });
}

main()
```

Comment: _"Here is what I have so far"_  this should be in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Phil, see last line. I will move it to the top.

Comment: I mean the actual code should be in your question as either a code block or runnable Stack Snippet

Comment: Ok, I have just added that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` is for looping through an Array. Use `map` to convert an Array to a new Array. Try:

```
function getChildren(comment: Comment, allComments: Comment[]) {
  return {
    ...comment,
    children: allComments
      .filter(c => String(c.parent_id) === comment.objectID)
      .map(c => getChildren(c, allComments))
  };
}
```

...which will give you the nested array of arrays you want.

However I'd recommend a different approach. Note that for each child you're looping through the entire collection. It's far more efficient to do one pass through the Array to collect the parent/child relationships:

```
const byParent = new Map<string, Array<Comment>>();
for (const comment of allComments) {
  let children = byParent.get(comment.parent_id);
  if (!children) {
    children = [];
    byParent.set(comment.parent_id, children);
  }
  children.push(comment);
}
```

Now you can do a `byParent.get(comment.objectID)` at any time to get child comments and do so recursively when necessary:

```
function getChildren(comment: Comment) {
  return {
    ...comment,
    children: byParent.get(comment.objectID)?.map(getChildren)
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to just output the entire JSON structure as described in my second codeblock, is looping `byParent` and doing `fullComments.push(...comments.map((comment) => getChildren(comment)));` the best way?

Comment: Nice, very clever complexity fix from O(n^2) to O(n)